# What makes an invalid core name?

Tags: solr

While devising a naming scheme for core names, I tried naming a core "search/live" and received this exception when trying to start solr:

```java
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid core name: search/live
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.registerCore(CoreContainer.java:411)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:499)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:249)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Evidently using `/` in a core name makes it invalid. What are the restricted characters that make a core name invalid? I can't seem to find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The valid characters for a core name appear to be undocumented. According to the source of `org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer#registerCore(String, SolrCore, boolean)` in Solr 4.10.4, the only invalid characters are:

- Forward-slash: `/`
- Back-slash: `\`

The following characters are problematic by causing issues in the admin interface and when performing general queries:

- Colon: `:`